# How to show the json sub values in to separate section in uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsindexpath

I have tried multiple methods,I have no idea for me. Can anyone show me the way to implement this.

json values:

```
    dict=@{
           @"car":@[@"hatchbag",@"sedan",@"suv"],
           @"waterpurifier":@[@"one litre",@"two litre",@"three litre"]

          };
```

My code:

```
   subArray=[dict objectforkey:@"car"];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section
    NSLog(@"expand section %d",expandSection);
    if (expandSection == section) {
        return [subArray count]+1;

    }
    else
        return 1;        
    }
 }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [arrPlayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_icon_29x29.png"];            
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }
```

Explanation:
I have stored the json value into separate array but I am not clear in  separating the the cells,how to show this data into separate cell friends.

```
Header:
car
->hatchbag
->sedan
->suv
waterpurifier
->0ne litre
->two litre
->three litre
```

How can I display the data in table view like this .

Answer (score 2):

You should use sections in your table view to group relevant data together.

Try this code :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section
    if (section==0) {
        return [[dict objectForKey:@"car"] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[dict objectForKey:@"waterpurifier"] count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"car"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter_icon_29x29.png"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[dict objectForKey:@"waterpurifier"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;// otherwise use dynamic condition like this way [[dict allKey] count]; -> return number of section 
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return [dict objectForKey:@"car"];
    }
    else
    {
        return [dict objectForKey:@"waterpurifier"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Missed answering it by a minute :) Good job.

Comment: after [[dict objectforkey:@"car"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] this object and indexpath didn't came for me

Comment: while am coding the objectAtIndex:indexPath.row did't came it show some error

Comment: s bro @DharmeshDhorajiya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85072/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-dharmesh-dhorajiya).

Answer (score 0):

*** swift 3.1**
this code is for swift 3.1 try it, maybe will be helpful.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
// Return the number of rows in the section
if section == 0 {

    return dict["car"].count()
}
else {

    return dict["waterpurifier"].count()
}
```

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

// Configure the cell...
if indexPath.section == 0 {

    cell?.textLabel?.text = dict["car"][indexPath.row]
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "twitter_icon_29x29.png")
}
else if indexPath.section == 1 {

    cell?.textLabel?.text = dict["waterpurifier"][indexPath.row]
}

cell?.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

```
return 2

// otherwise use dynamic condition like this way [[dict allKey] count]; -> return number of section
```

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

```
if section == 0 {

    return dict["car"]
}
else {

    return dict["waterpurifier"]
}
```

}